# Get query from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

My question is, how to get through an sql query, the data pointed out.

Comment: you have to tell us how you picked those rows out of the set.

Comment: Please review [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I would have to give you all my tables

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE Encabezado = 'Bastante Probable' AND EjeX IN ('Muy Alto/Bastante Probable','Muy Bajo/Bastante Probable') AND EjeY IN ('Alta/Optima', 'Alta/Baja', 'Alta/Deficeinte', 'Alta/Media')
```

However, you still should ask question more clearly, I am not 100% sure my select query will satisfy your needs.